# Maven install of a submodule on post clean of main project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho, multi-module

In my Maven project I have several submodules. They have some dependencies on each other (no circle though) and I'm using the `tycho-plugin` as well.

Now one of these submodules is fetching external dependencies for the rest. Because of tycho I need to run `mvn -clean install` on this one submodule before I can do so with the rest. Otherwise Tycho won't be able to resolve these dependencies, since it needs them to be available beforehand.

Is it possible to configure the build properties of this one submodule to initiate it's own `mvn install` directly after the `post-clean` phase?

That way I could (in theory) just run `mvn -clean install` on the main project to build all of them.

#### EDIT

My project structure is like this:

```
+- Project A
   +- submodule A
   +- submodule B
   +- submodule C
```

Now submodule `B` & `C` both need the external dependencies from `A`.
`B` & `C` are also using the `tycho-plugin`. This plugin needs all external dependencies in my local repository on start. Later added dependencies will be ignored and result in an *unresolvable dependency error*.

Currently I build `submodule A` first and then `Project A` without that submodule. That way Tycho is happy and runs just fine.

So my main goal would be to have `submodule A` run it's `mvn -clean install` before the other projects are scanned/triggered so when Tycho is started all external dependencies are in my local repository.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if your submodules depend on each other, Maven will make sure that the dependant modules are built first. Can you post your current project structure, some sample POMs and the error you have?

Comment: If this submodule needed to be run first you dependencies in your MANIFEST.MF files are not correct or you are missing a dependency on that submodule in the pom (depends if you are using pom first or MANIFEST first approach)...

Comment: @Tunaki The problem is not with maven but with tycho. It's a plugin to build eclipse-projects and this one needs the external dependencies to be installed in my local repository before it is triggered otherwise it will ignore them.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using pom first approach. In my poms i have all dependencies I need and the pom also rewirites the MANIFEST.MF if needed. If I run the submodule first and the main later (without ths submodule ofc) then everything runs just finde.

Comment: That sounds if you miss some dependency otherwise maven will automatically order the build order appropriately. Just start the build from root module and do `mvn clean install` ...There is an output at the beginning which shows the "Reactor Order" there you can see if this working or not. If not you miss dependencies.